# How to NOT hide taskbar item during using hide()

Tags: qt, show-hide, qt5, minimize

When I do hide() on my window, it hides but with taskbar icon. I want to skip hiding tray icon to let me restore it by clicking on it. Is it possible? I don't want use minimize.

user push button -> window hide but he has icons on taskbar (and maybe on systray) and now he can restore it by clicking on taskbar item (or maybe tray icon). I know how to do this working with trayicon but can't get how to stop from hiding taskbar item and all i find is "How to hide taskbar item?".

thanks

Comment: why you down wnat to use showMinimized? It works actualy as you described.

Comment: minimized do something wrong with event i added by AddFilterEvents. After i make ->show() none is working. I tried many ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
Maybe someone will need this someday in problems with restore from minimizing using frameless window

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent( QEvent* e )
{

  if( e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
  {
    if(this->windowState() & Qt::WindowMinimized )
    {
       //do something after minimize
    }
    else
    {
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Window); //show normal window
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
     //and again frameless. somethign like refreshing frameless windows after minimize
        this->showNormal();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShowMinimised()` does exactly what your asking for

however if this doesnt work because of some function you have overridden then provide a code sample please

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is that window is framelss Qt::FramelessWindowHint without this all look fine but with this after I restore window from minimize I have issues with actions in app.
Help 1. I will find reason why it can't restore properly
Help 2. I can do this by HIDE() but I can't lose taskbar icon(Main question)

Thanks for every help!